# Cursor snaps to top monitor but only if 3rd monitor is on the right side

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

I have a pretty common (these days) three monitor setup. However, they all run at a different resolution: 3840x2160, 3440x1440, and 2560x1440. I've been using this setup for a long time now, and I've never had any complaints. However, I decided to move my setup around, and now the portrait monitor is on the right side instead of the left side.

This is the screen layout:

[image]

Basically no matter what I do, when I move my cursor from monitor 3 to monitor 2, it goes to the bottom right corner of monitor 1 instead. Take a look at this video: https://i.imgur.com/uz0QyvG.mp4

What's even weirder is that it's really inconsistent: https://i.imgur.com/Cbl2Yoo.mp4

I can get it to stop pretty consistently by moving my mouse around at supersonic speeds, but that's definitely not something I'm interested in. I have tried every possible position I can think of (gap-wise in the Display Settings menu), but the only thing that works 100% of the time, is if I move monitor 3 to the left side.

The first time I sat at my PC with this new setup, I installed the new 22H2 update. I'm not sure if that's the culprit.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you rotate the screen 180 degrees (just move the bottom to the top) and 'flip' the portrait mode?

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem like it. It's a bit hard to test, obviously, but nope it seems like it's only in this configuration. It's so weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping to the nearest corner instead of sticking is a new feature as of Windows 11 build 22557 - handy for if you have some gap between displays, or when two displays don't line up

It looks like windows is sometimes failing to tell there's an adjacent display instead of a gap. It seems like this is more common with the "top" of a display, so that may be why it only affects one side for you. You can disable the feature here (it's in your screenshot):

> Settings > System > Display > Multiple Displays > Ease cursor movement between displays

You might also have some luck just moving the display boxes around until Windows decides to "snap" them closer or better, but it seems like buggy behavior for now.

Comment: Dang, yep, that was it. Works perfectly now it seems. Odd. Why would they release such a feature AND make it default when it's buggy. Dammit. Thanks!